# Can the axis line be shown on the topmost in Excel?

Tags: excel

As shown in the Figure below, there are some points on the x-axis. As a result, part of the x-axis line is hidden by these points (see the red arrows).

Can we make the axis line appear totally on the topmost of the layer? For example, like applying the "Bring to Front" function to the x-axis.

[image: Figure]

Comment: No, but you could make the data points slightly transparent, or use an additional dummy series to plot the axis line. Why is it important?

Comment: @Rory Thanks Rory! Not so important, but I just want to make the axis complete ...

Comment: @Rory Could you explain a little bit about how to "use an additional dummy series" to achieve it?

Comment: Add a new XY series with X values as your min and max current X values, and Y values of 0, format with a line and that should do it. Almost forgot: you need to plot it on a secondary axis!

Comment: @Rory Thanks! It works! I will close this question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accroding to Rory's comment, we can add a dummy series and then draw it as a line in the secondary axis. It will appear like the Figure below, make sure the second axis's range is the same as your original x-axis, then that dummy series's line will serve as your x-axis.
[image: Fig2]

Comment: FYI you should be able to delete the secondary axis and keep the desired effect.